# Combining multiple-row data into a single row

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table that has columns like following

```
ID  Number  Value1  User1  Value2  User2  Value3  User3
--  ------  ------  -----  ------  -----  ------  ------
1   123     0       Jack
1   123                    1       TOM
1   123                                   2       Tim
1   456     0       Jones
1   456                    1       Jim
1   456                                   2       Carter
```

I need result like the following,

```
ID  Number  Value1  User1  Value2  User2  Value3  User3
--  ------  ------  -----  ------  -----  ------  ------
1   123     0       Jack   1       TOM    2       Tim
1   456     0       Jones  1       Jim    2       Carter
```

Can anyone please help me out on this?

The column *ID* remains same. The columns *Value* and *User* will go till *Value6* and *User6* and each row has values like one below the other. I need to combine all of them and show it as a single row.

Comment: Is this really a table or is this the result of a query? Would it be possible (and wiser) to fix that query? If not, what are the blank bits? Are they nulls or are they spaces/empty strings?

Comment: Look  like you have value in all fields, you can do it in PHP or ASP by just iterating through the collection and checking if value is present , then save those, if you want to do it faster, use T-Sql (tell me if you need help)

Comment: i think its table structure

Answer (score 0):

Simple Group by will work for your expected output

```
select 
columnid,
Number,
max(Value1) as value1, max(User1)as user1 , max(Value2) as value2,  max(User2) as user2,max(Value3) as value3,max(User3) as user3
from 
table
group by
columnid,
number
```

Comment: This will work nicely as long as there is only one value in each column within a grouping - and that is what the example data shows. However if the source data ever has multiple values for the same column within a group, the MAX statements will not necessarily get the values that @Nithin is hoping for.

Comment: I have clarified that  as "for your expected output"